# What is the Microsoft Graph API equivalent to UserAccountControl from Active Directory API?

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

What is the Microsoft Graph API equivalent to UserAccountControl from Active Directory API found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties

I've been looking everywhere, but there is no straightforward answer. The closest is probably AccountEnabled on Graph API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0%2F#properties

Comment: Yes, `accountEnabled` is the equivalent of bit 2 from `userAccountControl`

Answer (score 0):

As of now don't think there is similar feature available in Microsoft Graph,
If you want you can raise a feature request for same in Microsoft 365 Developer Platform portal:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform